# barchart of the 5 most common projects

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to display the different projects with the number of times they occur.  I would like to only display the top projects (the X most common projects). I would like to plot it out like this example. How can I create such a plot?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Nameid': [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2],
    'Name': ['Michael', 'Max', 'Susan', 'Michael', 'Mike' ,'Max'],
    'Project': ['S455', 'G874', 'S455', 'G874', 'S455', 'O274'],
})
display(df.head(10))
```

[image]

I tried it with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(df['Project'])]

plt.bar(x_pos, df['Project'], color='green')
plt.xticks(x_pos, df['Project'])

plt.show()
```

It doesn't even look like ...
How can I make it look like the example with the different genres?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating the dataframe you can use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to calculate the frequency of each `Project` in the dataframe.

```py
gb = df.groupby("Project").size()
# Project
# S455    3
# G874    2
# O274    1
# dtype: int64
```

To plot this we can call [`plot.barh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.barh.html) on the resultant `Series` to plot a horizontal bar chart:

```py
gb.plot.barh()
```

[image: horizontal bar plot]

---

We can chain on [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) to get the top 5, like so:

```py
gb = df.groupby("Project").size().nlargest(n=5, keep="first")
```

This can be plotted in the same way.

---

This is a bit hacky:

To get colours and a legend we can get a [`colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) and use `cm.get_cmap` to get a palette (in this case I've used `Pastel1`). We then provide the colour map to `barh` and place the legend.

```py
import matplotlib.cm as cm

ax = gb.plot.barh(color=cm.get_cmap("Pastel1").colors)
ax.legend(ax.get_children(), gb.index, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer! Is there an option to give the bars different colours and the legend? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The legend duplicates the data on the y axis. I've managed to do it but I don't think it's a good idea.